# Export Data from HiveQL to MySQL using Oozie with Sqoop

Tags: mysql, export, hiveql, sqoop, oozie

I have a table (regularly updated) in Hive that I want to have in one of my tool that has a MySQL database. I can't just connect my application to the Hive database, so I want to export those data directly in the MySQL database.

I've searched a bit and found out that it was possible with Sqoop, and I've been told to use Oozie since I want to regularly update the table and export it.

I've looked around for a while and tried some stuff but so far I can't succeed, and I just don't understand what I'm doing.

So far, the only code I understand but doesn't work looks like that :

```
export --connect jdbc:mysql://myserver
--username username
--password password
--table theMySqlTable
--hive-table cluster.hiveTable
```

I've seen people using temporary table and export it on a txt file to then export it, but I'm not sure I can do it. 
Should Oozie have specific parameters too ? I'm not the administrator so I'm not sure if I'm able to do it...

Thank you !

Comment: Could you please try below script

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
sqoop export \
--connect "jdbc:sqlserver://servername:1433;databaseName=EMP;" \
--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager \
--username userid \
-P \
--table theMySqlTable\
--input-fields-terminated-by '|' \
--export-dir /hdfs path location of file/part-m-00000 \
--num-mappers 1 \
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I've find some informations online and I now know better how to use that command, but I'm still getting error
I use "jdbc:MySQL://MYSERVERURL:3306;databaseName=MYDBNAME;" (tried with jdbc:MySQL://MYSERVERURL:3306/MYDBNAME too, doesn't work)

Comment: @Lorsio-- what are you are getting? It's working for me

Comment: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".

But my error is different from last time I was working on it. Last time I used "export --connect jdbc:mysql://SERVERURL:3306/DBNAME --verbose --username USERNAME --password PASSWORD --table MySQLTABLE --export-dir DIR" and sqoop just couldn't reach my MySQL server. I'm wondering if MySQL is listening to sqoop and how I could alter that

Comment: @Lorsio-- could you please give a try using databaseNames instead of databaseName

Comment: or you can also try providing schema in connection string. ;schema=my_schema; I remember, I had similar problems when I was doing it. Let me know if it works

Comment: Still not working, event when I'm working around every error I have. Like my database is a MySQL and not a SQLServer one, so I changed everything to do quite the same. The error I got is "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure" ; and then I have "[main] ERROR org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool  - Encountered IOException running export job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter"
Still looking for an answer right now

Comment: Even a list-tables does not work. I'm providing the right address, the right dbname/schema for MySQL, the right username and password. Should be able to work, it has the right priviledge. Seems like sqoop can't reach my MySQL server...